# jQuery validate - CSV email regex without trailing comma

Tags: jquery, regex

The code I'm working on for a custom validation in .validate is below. I want to allow the user to enter email addresses separated by a comma but I'm stuck with my regex on disallowing the trailing comma.

`aaa@foo.com, bbb@bar.com` = ok

`aaa@foo.com,bbb@bar.com` = ok

`aaa@foo.com,` = NOT ok (note this is a trailing space here too)

`aaa@foo.com,` = NOT ok

But my problem is all the above in the below are ok.

```
$.validator.addMethod('csvEmail', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^((([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))+(,|, |$))*$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid email address or multiple valid addresses separated by a comma.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `regex` expression is that you are matching the first column `aaa@foo.com` along with the `,` or `,(space)` or `(end of the line)`. Then, you are checking if it is repeating `0` or more times, by using the `*`.

However, here, you cannot use the `*` or the `+` sign. You want it to match `2` times **always**. Therefore, you would want the fix your `regex` to the following:

```
^((([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))+(,|, |$)){2}$
```

> If you did not notice, I removed the `*` before the `$` at the end, and replaced it with `{2}`. This is because you want 2 matches.

---

However, I would go with the following `regex` expression:

```
(.+?)@(.+)\.(.+),[^\S\r\n]*(.+?)@(.+)\.(.+)
```

---

Anyway, both return the results you want, out of the following:

```
aaa@foo.com, bbb@bar.com
aaa@foo.com,bbb@bar.com
aaa@foo.com, 
aaa@foo.com,
```

They highlight only the following:

```
aaa@foo.com, bbb@bar.com
aaa@foo.com,bbb@bar.com
```

> In case you wish to try it out yourself, [click here](https://regexr.com/4shh9), and change the `regex` between both. They both work.